# Unable to remove <xml> and <style> tags from a string using JSOUP

Tags: java, xml, tags, jsoup

I have a string which contains the following html code:

```
 ...
 ...
 <style>
   v\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   o\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   w\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
   .shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}
</style>
<xml>
   <w:WordDocument>
   <w:View>Normal</w:View>
   <w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>
   <w:TrackMoves>false</w:TrackMoves>
</xml>
...
...
```

and when i apply

```
string.select("style").remove();
string.select("xml").remove();
```

nothing seems to happen. What i am doing wrong? I want to completely remove those tags including their content.

Comment: Please, provide a working example that displays the problem you are experiencing. I think you might be removing the `Element` from the `Document` just as intended, but instead are looking at the `Elements` collection or something like that.

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes please mark it so the topic can be considered closed, if not please provide some feedback, or an answer of your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String xmlStr = "<style>" +
                            "v\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}" +
                            "o\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}" +
                            "w\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}" +
                            ".shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}" +
                            "</style>" +
                            "<xml>" +
                            "<w:WordDocument>" +
                            "<w:View>Normal</w:View>" +
                            "<w:Zoom>0</w:Zoom>" +
                            "<w:TrackMoves>false</w:TrackMoves>" +
                            "</xml>";

            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xmlStr, "", Parser.xmlParser());
            doc.select("style").remove();
            System.out.println(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<xml>
 <w:worddocument>
  <w:view>
   Normal
  </w:view>
  <w:zoom>
   0
  </w:zoom>
  <w:trackmoves>
   false
  </w:trackmoves>
 </w:worddocument>   //Added by jsoup during normalization of the xml document
</xml>
```